# Edit text within a cell (jquery datatables)

Tags: jquery, datatables

Is it possible to edit the text within a cell in datatables. So that when the user double clicks on the cell it becomes editable ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://jquery-datatables-editable.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/inline-edit.html

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $(function(){
    $('#mod').click(function(){
    $('#text1').html('<input id="no" size="'+$(this).text().length+'" type="text" value="'+ $('#text1').text() + '">');  
    });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="text1"> Text Here </p>
    <input type="button" id="mod" name="modify"  value="modify" />
```